# How to squash typeORM migration files into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

My migration files is becoming pretty big and I'm curious if there's a way to squash the migration files into one with TypeORM without resorting to pure SQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to squash all your existing TypeORM migrations into a single file, you can follow these steps (little mix between @Alexandre & @0xCAP):

1. Delete all existing migrations in your project directory (including the compiled .js files).
2. Make sure your local database schema is also empty (no tables).
3. Run the following command to generate a new migration: `typeorm migration:generate path/to/SquashedMigrations -d path/to/datasource`

This will create a new migration file named "12345678910-squashedmigrations.ts" that includes all the changes from your previous migrations.

```
export class squashedMigrations12345678910 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'squashedMigrations12345678910'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE ...`);
```

4. Rename the generated migration name to match the name of the latest migration you've applied in production. For example, if the latest migration you've applied is "lastMigration1634532141863", you should rename "squashedMigrations12345678910" to "lastMigration1634532141863".

```
-- name = 'squashedMigrations12345678910'
++ name = 'lastMigration1634532141863'
```

Note that when you rename the squashed migration name to match the latest migration you've applied in production, TypeORM will consider the migration as already applied and won't execute it again, even without the `--fake` option. Therefore, you don't need to use `--fake` in this case.

This approach assumes that you haven't made any changes to your production database schema outside of TypeORM migrations. If that's not the case, you'll need to make sure to merge any changes manually before running the squashed migration. (Ex: Trigger, sql functions...)

Comment: Thank you. This approach makes sense. Also, I think that it might be useful to remove all the rows from the "migrations" table except the last one or even rename it and the newly created migration file to the appropriate name for this operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as 0xCAP said. But when the new migration is created you should not run it in production, it will fail because everything has already be done.
You can fake it using the `--fake` command option in [typeorm documentation](https://typeorm.io/migrations#faking-migrations-and-rollbacks)

`typeorm migration:run --fake`

It will mark the migration as done without executing it.

Otherwise you can modify the regex of migrations path. Exemple :

```
migrations: process.env.SKIP_MIGRATION ? ['${rootDir}/../migrations/!(mysquashedmigration){.ts,.js}'] : ['${rootDir}/../migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
```

Answer (score -1):

You could delete them all, then regenerate a migration. The newly generated migration would contain all of the previous migrations.

Comment: that is not a valid option if you are already running on production

Comment: The newly generated migration would still run in production which is not something that should happen on live production environment.